# Django 3.1 JSONField attempts to deserialized dict

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

I am running into issues using the new `django.db.models.JSONField` where it appears the column comes back from the database already deserialized i.e. already a `dict`. The model attempts to deserialize the value again resulting an exception.

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

This exception is being thrown from `json.loads` call in the `from_db_value` method on the `JSONField` class definition.

```py
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        try:
            return json.loads(value, cls=self.decoder)
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            return value
```

We are running postgres and the column is defined in the database as `json` i.e. not `jsonb`. My models that have columns that are `jsonb` do not appear to have this error.

I do not appear to have the issue when the the column on the model is saved as a string. Only when the column is a `dict`.

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = models.JSONField()


m1 = MyModel(data=json.dumps({"key": "value"})
m1.save()
m1.refresh_from_db()

m2 = MyModel(data={"key": "value")
m2.save()
m2.refresh_from_db() # Exception thrown here
```

My guess is that it is being double encoded in this case. Whatever is causing it to be decoded into a `dict` is decoding it and then it's being decoded into a `dict` at the model level.

```py
>>> import json
>>> a = json.dumps({"key": "value"})
>>> a
'{"key": "value"}'
>>> json.dumps(a)
'"{\\"key\\": \\"value\\"}"'
```

I've even tried sticking with the Postgres specific field and that has the same issue. There are already records in our DB that caused this issue and thus I can't save the column w/ the value already `json.dumps`. Which I don't even think fixes the issue anyway.

Dependencies

```
Django==3.1.3
psycopg2==2.8.6
```

Comment: It's a `JSONField` because it handles JSON automatically. So, no need to load or dump. If you really really want to do it manually use a TextField.

Comment: I understand that. Like I said I don't want to `json.dumps` the column. Please reread what I wrote.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32135 Quote: *"It looks that you use json instead of jsonb datatype in your database, which is not supported."*

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the crux of the issue appears to be `json` vs. `jsonb`. I wasn't aware they really didn't support `json`. It worked fine until I upgraded to 3.1. My impression is that is when the kinda implied support was dropped. It looks like we're going to have to migrate that column to `jsonb`

Comment: In my case i was using an unmanaged Django table, so when i created the `json` field in my database wasn't aware of this limitation. So my solution was to simply change to `jsonb`.